# travis-ci problems with LaTeX overfull box (warning = error)

Tags: r, build, latex, travis-ci

I'm struggling with a travis-ci R build when trying to create the manuals (R CMD build). Everything runs smoothly when *not compiling the manuals/vignettes* (`--no-build-vignettes`). The problem is that LaTeX throws a warning of an overfull box (DOIs of some of the references) which causes an error ("build failed").

Does anyone have had the same issue? I mean, I could remove the `\doi` tags, but that's not what I really want to do.

**Is it possible** to tell travis-ci **not to freak out** on **overfull boxes** (LaTeX)? Maybe a flag which sets LaTeX warnings to "not critical"?

Would help me a lot!

Thanks in advance

The tail of the travis log:

```
...
(/home/travis/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/inconsolata/ts1zi4.fd) [3]
(/home/travis/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def) [4]
(/home/travis/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def) [5]
(/home/travis/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def)
(/home/travis/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def) [6]
(/home/travis/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ts1ptm.fd)
(/home/travis/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def) [7]
(/home/travis/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def) [8] [9]
Overfull \hbox (110.11986pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 571--574
```

... and that's it. build failed.